# FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION nothing touched

Tags: android, libgdx

Yesterday the app was launching fine. Today´s first launch gave me:

```
.android E/JavaBinder﹕ !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
 D/Error﹕ ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 1394196
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ Error reporting crash
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
```

I haven´t touched the code since yesterday.. what can cause this out of nowhere?

Comment: My 'wild' guess is that you are passing something in intent that is large (size), probably a large image as byte[].. There is a limit with how much data intents can hold so if that is the case post your code and people might help you.

Comment: Your "wild" guess was rather good. I passed an screenshot of the screen as you described with byte[] , controlling that method sorted it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a 1 MB limit for any binder transaction.
If you need to send anything larger than that like a screenshot - then u are better off in storing that screenshot and sending a URL to access it via a provider.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the uri of the file not the byte[]